# JS alert is messing up HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have an mp4 video on my site that I play with `$("#movie").get(0).play()`. That works fine.

However, if I do `alert("anything");` and then try playing the movie, the movie only advances a few frames (I get sound too). Then it freezes. The video controls still show "pause" being an option, so the player still thinks it's playing. I have to refresh the screen, and avoid `alert()`ing anything in order to play the whole video. How can I get around this problem?

I'm on the newest version of Chrome on a Macbook Pro with the newest Yosemite.

Comment: don't use alert(). it's basically a giant "stop sign" for anything JS related until you hit 'ok'.

Comment: Consider using a modal if you need to pop up some information. Personally, I hate alert() with a passion.

Comment: Try using a jQuery dialog instead. See if that works better for you: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Ok, guess I'll stick to `console.log`. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Look out for one of the latest fancy javascript notification libs (the UI works out as the notification messages in OSX for instance). It will give you a much better look&feel than a dreadful alert.